# How to Append Bootstrap Checkbox to a dataTable in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to append bootstrap checkboxes dynamically through jquery ajax.
But only checkbox appends, and i couldn't call bootstrap class to it.

> My Code:

```
var checkbox = '<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes">';
//checkboxes is my bootstrap class

$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( arr_data ) {  
  $('#example').dataTable().fnAddData([checkbox, arr_data[i].name]);
});
```

As a result of above code, checkbox class doesn't get applied.

Comment: Do you make any initialization on the `.checkboxes` checkboxes?

Comment: Yeah, i tried by adding the "checkboxes" class using .addClass() but does'n work. It works only on page refresh.

Comment: You can use `columnDefs` & `mRender` option for this.

Comment: I meant that if you apply any plugin on the checkboxes e.g. `jQuery('.checkboxes').anyPlugin({});`

Comment: columnDefs and mRender doesn't work. Should I Try to initialize something like Bootstrap function call in Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jQuery's append?  I'm assuming you're trying to add everything to "#example". I'm also assuming you're going to get more than one thing from your AJAX call.

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( arr_data ) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr_data.length; i++) {
    $('#example').append('<input type="checkbox" +class="checkboxes">'
      + arr_data[i].name)
  }
});
```